# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.reactivex.Flowable

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I am using **`RxJava Version  2.0.1.`** Using **`Android Studio 3.0 Canary 6`**.

I have some code like this

```
private void subscribeToObservable(Observable<List<CalendarDto>> observable) {
    DisposableObserver<List<CalendarDto>> d = getDisposableimportantDaysObserver();
    observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(d);
    disposables.add(d);
}
```

But the problem is My app crashes whenever I run this code in android device with API 19( Kitkat, have not checked lower than that) , but it runs fine in my android 7.0 emulator. The Error log

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.reactivex.Flowable
>                at io.reactivex.Observable.bufferSize(Observable.java:126)
>                at io.reactivex.Observable.observeOn(Observable.java:8412)

This is not because of my proguard as I deleted all the code in the proguard config file but the issue was still there.

Does anyone have Idea what might be going wrong ?

Comment: Probably multidex is your problem: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.reactivex.Flowable at
>   io.reactivex.Observable.bufferSize(Observable.java:126) at
>   io.reactivex.Observable.observeOn(Observable.java:8412)

**Don't**

```
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

**Do**

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread(),false,100) // Add SIZE
```

Comment: Thanks bro, you saved my day :)

Comment: I was too early when I tried to accept, so it didnt let me accept :)  Thanks for the remainder